# How to save the results of a for function in an excel file

Tags: python, data-manipulation

I need to save all the results from this loop into an excel sheet file:

```
import itertools


def foo(l):
     yield from itertools.product(*([l] * 18)) 
 

for x in foo('ATCG'):
    print(''.join(x))`
```

I tried this:

```
import itertools
import csv


def foo(l):
     yield from itertools.product(*([l] * 18)) 


for x in foo('ATCG'):
    print(''.join(x))
    outfile =  open("primers.csv","w", newline = '')
    writer=csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(str(foo))
```

but it ended up saving only the last result of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only create the writer once outside the loop or it will overwrite the file completely with each line. Like this:

```
import csv
import itertools


def foo(l):
     yield from itertools.product(*([l] * 4))


outfile = open("primers.csv","w")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

for x in foo('ATCG'):
    row = ''.join(x)
    print(row)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Note that your loop creates a lot of permutations, it might not end for a very, very long time and the file will be huge:

```
AAAAAATGTGTAAGAACT
AAAAAATGTGTAAGAACC
AAAAAATGTGTAAGAACG
AAAAAATGTGTAAGAAGA
AAAAAATGTGTAAGAAGT
```

Comment: for experimental purposes i edit the function to :
def foo(l):
     yield from itertools.product(*([l] * 2)) 

so that I can test the results faster 


but your code didn't solve the problem, it still gave me an empty excel sheet file

Comment: How should the columns be arranged in the file? All the letters in one column?

Comment: @NadeenNBY I've updated the code to what I think you want. It creates a long excel sheet.

Comment: yes, i want them all to be in the same column, also if you happen to know a better way to save huge data other than excel that would be extremely helpful

Comment: for some reason i still get an empty excel file, even tho I copied your code as it is

Comment: It could be that the file is in use, you could try changing the name to primers2.csv. Or maybe the python is having an error if the indenting isn't perfect from the copy and paste?

Comment: the code runs and gives perfect results in the console but the file is empty, I did try changing the name and it still didn't work.
i really appreciate your help, I'm new to this

Comment: Try changing the name to end with .txt and see if another program (notepad) opens it.

Comment: also an empty text file

Comment: If you are running the program like this `python program.py`, you can run `python program.py > filename.csv` to save it to a file.

Comment: now it worked, thank you very much. but can I know how to get the results 'like each 18 character' in the same column

Comment: I don't understand, how would that look? Like | T | A | G | or |TAG|?

Comment: i want all the results to be in the same column "that's gonna be "A" in the excel sheet and they would look like this AAAAAATGTGTAAGAACT, and arranged just like they are arranges in the printed results in the console and like you have typed the results in your answer

Comment: `writer.writerow([row])` instead of `writer.writerow(row)` will put it all in one column

Comment: perfect. thank you so much !!! you've been a great help